# Matplotlib 3D quiver arrow heads scaling error?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

The 3D matplotlib quiver arrow heads seem to scale strange and the head angles seem to disappear. Is this expected behavior? Plotting a helix and its derivative:

```
t = np.array([ foo for foo in np.arange(0, 10*pi, 1) ])
x = np.column_stack([np.cos(t/5), np.sin(t/5), t**2])
dx = np.column_stack([-1/5 *np.sin(t/5), 1/5* np.cos(t/5), 2*t] )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(*x.T)
q=ax.quiver( *x.T, *dx.T, arrow_length_ratio=0.01, color='r')
plt.show()
```

With `arrow_length_ratio=0` we get reasonable behavior for the arrow shafts:

[image: No arrowheads]

At `arrow_length_ratio=0.01` we see weird track-track looking arrow heads that seem as though one half of the arrow head has its angle backwards:

[image: Weird arrowheads]

The default `arrow_length_ratio` gives some insane arrow head scaling:

[image: Insanity]

Is this all expected behavior or a bug?

Comment: This might well be a bug, possibly related https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11746.